# Optimizing Language Detection code and Lemmatization in Python

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, lemmatization, textblob

I have a data of amazon user reviews in JSON format which i am importing to pandas dataframe and using it to train a  model for text classification. I am trying to preprocess the user review text before training a model with that data. I have two questions here:

1) I have written a code to detect it's language using Textblob library in Python which is working fine but consuming a lot of time. Please tell me if there can be a optimal approach.I am using Textblob library in python and the code is:

```
    from textblob import TextBlob
    def detect_language(text):
        if len(text)>3:
            r=TextBlob(text)
            lang = r.detect_language()
            return lang
    dataset['language']=dataset.reviewText.apply(lambda x: detect_language(x))
```

2) I want to lemmatize my words before training the model. But as lemmatization in NLTK will work properly if the we have parts-of-speech tagged with the words, I am trying it as follows but getting some error:

```
    from nltk import pos_tag
    from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
    text='my name is shubham'
    text=pos_tag(text.split())
    wl=WordNetLemmatizer()
    for i in text:
        print(wl.lemmatize(i))
```

Here i am getting pos tagged as:

```
    [('my', 'PRP$'), ('name', 'NN'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('shubham', 'JJ')]
```

and while doing lemmatization i am getting error as:

```
    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Can you please suggest an efficient way to perform lemmatization.
Here is my sample data on which i am performing language detection and lemmatization:

```
    overall reviewText
        5   Not much to write about here, but it does exac...
        5   The product does exactly as it should and is q...
        5   The primary job of this device is to block the...
        5   Nice windscreen protects my MXL mic and preven...
        5   This pop filter is great. It looks and perform...
```

Comment: Need more info on the error msg. Which line is causing it and if it is when wl.lemmeatize then print i before doing it.

Comment: @gout i am getting error in `print(wl.lemmatize(i))`. I tried printing i and got to know that it is giving error for the first word itself i.e. ('my', 'PRP$').

Comment: Take a look at https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk and https://gist.github.com/alvations/07758d02412d928414bb

Comment: @alvas I am able to do it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

```
from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()

def penn2morphy(penntag):
    """ Converts Penn Treebank tags to WordNet. """
    morphy_tag = {'NN':'n', 'JJ':'a',
                  'VB':'v', 'RB':'r'}
    try:
        return morphy_tag[penntag[:2]]
    except:
        return 'n' 

def lemmatize_sent(text): 
    # Text input is string, returns lowercased strings.
    return [wnl.lemmatize(word.lower(), pos=penn2morphy(tag)) 
            for word, tag in pos_tag(word_tokenize(text))]
```

To lemmatize a dataframe column of string.

```
df['lemmas'] = df['text'].apply(lemmatize_sent)
```

## In Long

Read https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk